# PHP DateTime diff format returns -0

Tags: php, datetime, datediff

I made a function who returns true if the difference between the current date and another date if inferior to x days.

Here is my function :

```
private function notBeforeDate($date_to_compare, $interval) {
    $now = new DateTime('now');
    $date = new DateTime($date_to_compare);
    $diff = $now->diff($date)->format("%r%a");

    return $diff < $interval ? true : false;
}
```

But when I send the same date `$diff` will returns -0 and day +1 will returns 0.

**E.g (assuming the current date is 2017-02-16) :**

```
$this->notBeforeDate('2017-02-15', 1); // $diff = -1
$this->notBeforeDate('2017-02-16', 1); // $diff = -0
$this->notBeforeDate('2017-02-17', 1); // $diff = 0
$this->notBeforeDate('2017-02-18', 1); // $diff = 1
```

How can I do to get a good value in my `$diff` variable ? I want this :

```
$this->notBeforeDate('2017-02-15', 1); // $diff = -1
$this->notBeforeDate('2017-02-16', 1); // $diff = 0
$this->notBeforeDate('2017-02-17', 1); // $diff = 1
$this->notBeforeDate('2017-02-18', 1); // $diff = 2
```

Comment: working fine with some changes:- https://eval.in/738465    (just an example)

Comment: 2017-02-17 and 2017-02-16 will returns 0 both. I want `1` if the received date is the day +1

Comment: Without diging in to it: `DateTime` sound like it returning the time also. "now" is right here for me 2017-02-16 13:48 witch is less then one day from both 2017-02-16 00:00:00 and 2017-02-17 00:00:00. I would suggest plaing with `Date` instead if its days your looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DateTime("now")` will return date and time. Given "now" at any time of day will be less than one day from any date that is the same or the next as long as the timestamp is less than 24 hour in either direction.

A short fix for you problem would be this:

```
private function notBeforeDate($date_to_compare, $interval) {
    $now = new DateTime(Date("Y-m-d"));
    $date = new DateTime($date_to_compare);
    $diff = $now->diff($date)->format("%r%a");

    return $diff < $interval ? true : false;
}
```

In this case, the time part is removed from "now". The better solution will be to create a solution that only use dates and not time at all.

Example:
IF `DateTime("now")` returns `2017-02-16 12:00' and you compare that to '2017-02-16 00:00:00' you get 0 days -12 hours. And the same for compare against '2017-02-17 00:00:00' that gives you 0 days +12 hours. When you ask for the day diff, you get the Day part that is 0 in both cases.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works well. I don't know why your answer has been downvoted. Could you explain why it works ?

Comment: Made an edit now. Hope that explains it, if not, I will try to explain further.

Comment: what about that `$diff` is a `DateInterval` and `$interval` only a number?

Comment: Your short fix works well for me. I just want to return an error if the received date exceeded 2 days

Comment: $diff is formatet whith  `"%r%a"`. This gives hole days according to documentation. So when internaly the diff might be 0.8, the %r%a parameter to format, tels the function to return 0.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the expected results:

```
    function notBeforeDate($date_to_compare) {
    $now = date_create('now');
    $date = date_create($date_to_compare);


    $diff=date_diff($now,$date);
    return $diff->format("%r%a");
}
var_dump( notBeforeDate('2017-02-17 12:48:00'))
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't solve my problem. $diff will be always -0 and 0 for the current date and the date +1